# php memory usage seems high - htmlpurifier in particular - methods for minimizing impact

Tags: php, memory, htmlpurifier

**UPDATE** Since most user activity is displaying data, I've chosen to move htmlpurifier to only purify data being saved to the database and then unset the created object when complete. Keeps memory usage much lower on loading pages.

---

I am evaluating the memory usage of my site with memory_get_peak_usage() and find that based on the code below, htmlpurifier is using 4,674,784 bytes and my whole page reports 12,320,768 (run in the footer).

```
$a = memory_get_peak_usage();
require_once './htmlpurifier-4.5.0-standalone/HTMLPurifier.standalone.php';
$b = memory_get_peak_usage();
var_dump($b - $a);
```

I know every app is different and "high" is subjective. Are there guidelines for when I "need" to reduce the memory footprint (how much is too much) - in terms of asking for trouble on a shared server?

I don't have a clue how to minimize htmlpurifier's impact since I use it on most pages to purify user post input. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can give the garbage collector a hint if you explicitly `unset()` the HTMLPurifier objects/resources. That won't lower the peak usage when using HTMLPurifier, but it the usage will definitely decrease directly after the `unset()` call.

Comment: The library uses this memory before I even call $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config). What would I unset?

Comment: That is probably due to some initializations. I cannot advise you since I don't know the internals of HTMLPurifier, sorry.